# Codeigniter Get Image Properties from Server Folder

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

How to get the Image Properties (Image size, Image height, Image width, Image file path) that already exists in the server folder to database. I have found that there is upload function in CI however I do not want to have duplicate images in the server but I just want the image file path as a reference.

Comment: Have a look at getimagesize , no special CI library needed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: If I need to auto detect whenever there are new images coming into the server is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to achieve , you'd use **getimagesize()**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php